# JasperReports: Ad Hoc, Drill Down report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have seen a few questions regarding Drill Down reports for *JasperReports*. I am trying to provide this functionality via *Ad Hoc* JR reports.

The goal(s) would be to use interactive charts or images to lead to move specific data tables and/or link back to data or a page in a web application.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Drill Down is supported just on Cross-tab reports via Jasper Reports Server Pro, and Table Report does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The web based Ad Hoc report designer does not have the ability to define hyperlinks to drill down. You need to edit the report in iReport to add hyperlinks like that.

Comment: conceptually, would it be possible to create a basic ad-hoc report, pull its JRXML file, implement hyperlinking in iReport and then load it back into the repository?

Comment: Yes. Once it's edited in iReport then Ad Hoc will no longer be able to deal with it. (That will change someday... but for now it's a one way street.)